# how to connect two lans together

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have two routers, #1 - d-link 6740u #2 siemens sl2-141.
I want to have two separate networks 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x
and I need to conect between the two.
My ISP is connected via #1
can this be done?
Thank you.

Comment: How big is your network? Although achievable, why do you want to add the complexity to your network?

Comment: Now I have them setup as one network, but the problem is that somtimes the main router crashes and I cannot join in to the network new devices (DHCP is only on the main router), But if I had two networks, if one crashed, the other one will keep working.

Comment: Could you simply remove the unreliable router so you use one? Or do you use the #2 as a network extender? You could reverse the devices so that #2 becomes #1 and provides DHCP reliably? Both devices are DSL modems also...?

Comment: I use it as an extender. #2 is less reliable then #1, but it only serves as a wifi switch, so I don't care.
Both devices are DSL but #1 is VDSL wich is much faster then ADSL

Comment: Which router do your devices connect to? Your network setup can't have two DHCP servers without you decidingif a certain subset of devices are on one and the others on the other. If #1 crashes then neither network will communicate. If you want failover DHCP your equipment cannot achieve this... I think you're asking something that your equipment is incapable of achieving. You could configure your network to use static IPs if your DHCP fails then some devices can communicate, but the two subnets won't be able to because the gateway will not be there.

Comment: this is a diagram of my network
[link-to-diagram](http://srv2.jpg.co.il/3/54026066f0a92.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just put some device in both networks and make sure every device that's another device's default gateway knows about the route to the other network.